'WebhookUtility' for job id '707Uo00000Krifj' : Callout loop not allowed
I have created this apex code for calling out to the  client portal. it works fine, when test it on sandbox.
But in Production it gives out error time to time :

Callout loop not allowed

This is the trigger and class im using as of now
Trigger
Trigger OpportunityTrigger On Opportunity (After Update)
{
    Public static Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap = (Map<Id, Opportunity>)Trigger.oldMap; 
    Public static List<Opportunity> oldList = (List<Opportunity>)Trigger.old;
    Public static Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap = (Map<Id, Opportunity>)Trigger.newMap; 
    Public static List<Opportunity> newList = (List<Opportunity>)Trigger.new;
    
    Public static Set<Id> setOfOppIdForUpdate = new Set<Id>();
    Public static Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOfOpp = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    Public static List<Opportunity> listOfOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<String> payloadList = new List<String>();
    
    
    If(!Trigger_Setting__c.getInstance().DisableOpportunityTrigger__c)
    {
        If(Trigger.IsAfter) 
        {
            if(Trigger.IsUpdate)
            {
                for(Opportunity opp : newList)
                {
                    if(opp.RecordTypeId == System.Label.Opportunity_Record_Type_Id)
                    {
                        listOfOpp.add(opp);
                        mapOfOpp.put(opp.id,oldMap.get(opp.id));
                        Opportunity oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);
                        
                        Map<String, Object> updatedFields = new Map<String, Object>();
                        
                        // Compare old and new field values
                        for (Schema.SObjectField field : Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
                        {
                            String fieldName = String.valueOf(field);
                            if (opp.get(fieldName) != oldAccount.get(fieldName) && fieldName != 'LastModifiedDate' && fieldName != 'SystemModstamp') 
                            {
                                updatedFields.put(fieldName, opp.get(fieldName));
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if (!updatedFields.isEmpty())
                        {
                            // Construct payload
                            Map<String, Object> payloadMap = new Map<String, Object>
                            {
                                    'updated_fields' => updatedFields,
                                    'object' => 'Opportunity',
                                    'id' => opp.Id
                            };
                                        
                            String payload = JSON.serialize(payloadMap);
                            
                            payloadList.add(payload);
                        }
                    } 
                    if(opp.RecordTypeId == System.Label.Opportunity_Record_Type_Id && opp.AirSlate_Vendor_Registration__c != Null && oldMap != null && opp.AirSlate_Vendor_Registration__c != oldMap.get(opp.id).AirSlate_vendor_Registration__c )
                    {
                        setOfOppIdForUpdate.add(opp.id);
                    }                    
                }
                If(!Trigger_Setting__c.getInstance().OpportunityWebhookDisable__c)
                {    
                    if (!payloadList.IsEmpty() && System.IsBatch() == false && System.isFuture() == false) 
                    {
                        WebhookUtility.sendWebhook(payloadList);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class
public class WebhookUtility 
{
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendWebhook(List<String> payloads) 
    {
        // Call the asynchronous method to handle callouts
        handleWebhookCallouts(payloads);
    }

    private static void handleWebhookCallouts(List<String> payloads) 
    {
        for(String payload : payloads) 
        {
            makeWebhookCallout(payload);
        }
    }

    // Method to make the actual callout
    private static void makeWebhookCallout(String payload) 
    {
        Map<String, Object> payloadMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
        String recordId = (String) payloadMap.get('id');
        String objectName = (String) payloadMap.get('object');
        String endpointURL = System.Label.WEBHOOK_URL + '' + objectName.toLowerCase() + '/' + recordId;
        System.debug('EndPoint URL => '+endpointURL);
        System.debug('payload => '+payload);
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setTimeout(60000);
        request.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
        request.setMethod('GET');

        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) 
        {
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            System.debug('Response => ' + response);
        }
    }
}

Please check and advise on the same
Thanks & Regards,
Himanshu B

Any chance that given webhook is triggered by update caused by another callout? This is a good example why this might happen - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387966&type=1

Note, too, that using future methods from a trigger is a flawed design. Take a look at this article plus this sample code.

Note also that your trigger logic should be delegated to a trigger handler (many existing frameworks) or you can simply have a dedicated handler class for this trigger. This way those nested ifs/loops can be turned into methods and the cyclomatic complexity of this logic goes way down
